# Programmatically access the Google Chrome Home or Start page

Tags: c#, google-chrome

Where does Chrome save the Home or Start page URL? I want to access it programmatically using C#.

Answer (score 34):

> ### Default locations are:
>
> #### Windows XP
>
> **Google Chrome:** `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
> **Chromium:** `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Chromium\User Data\Default`
>
> #### Vista / 7
>
> **Google Chrome:** `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
> **Chromium:** `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default`
>
> #### Mac OS X
>
> **Google Chrome:** `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`
> **Chromium:** `~/Library/Application Support/Chromium/Default`
>
> #### Linux
>
> **Google Chrome:** `~/.config/google-chrome/Default`
> **Chromium:** `~/.config/chromium/Default`

Source: Google Chromium user data directory default locations. ( [link](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) )

In amount of time I spent on writing this, this was the shortest and most robust example I could think of (I completely ignored the fact, that user could use different location then default). Must say, it was bit trickier, then I thought.

In this example, I try using the default location directory, and finding the preference file where the "Home" is stored. It is stored in [JSon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format, so I deserialize the data that I am interested, and print it out.

Win 7 Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
//References -> Add Reference -> "System.Runtime.Serialization" Add
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

namespace test {
    class Program {
        [DataContract]
        public class Mdata {
            [DataMember(Name = "homepage")] 
            public String homepage { get; private set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "homepage_is_newtabpage")]
            public Boolean isNewTab { get; private set; }
            public Mdata() { }
            public Mdata(String data) {
                homepage = data;
            }
        }

        public static Mdata FindData(String json) {
            Mdata deserializedData = new Mdata();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(deserializedData.GetType());
            deserializedData = ser.ReadObject(ms) as Mdata;
            ms.Close();
            return deserializedData;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            const int LikeWin7 = 6;
            OperatingSystem osInfo = Environment.OSVersion;
            DirectoryInfo strDirectory;
            String path=null, file=null, data;

            if (osInfo.Platform.Equals(System.PlatformID.Win32NT))
                if (osInfo.Version.Major == LikeWin7)
                    path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData") +
                        @"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default";
            if (path == null || path.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Fail. Bad OS.");
            if (!(strDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(path)).Exists)
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Fail. The directory was not fund");
            if (!new FileInfo(file = Directory.GetFiles(strDirectory.FullName, "Preferences*")[0]).Exists)
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Fail. The file was not found.", file);

            Mdata info = FindData(data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file));
            Console.WriteLine(info.homepage);
            Console.WriteLine(info.isNewTab);
        }
    }
}
```

Example output for Me:

```
chrome://newtab
True
```

Hope I get at least 1 up vote :P

Comment: I tried to manually change Preferences file.However, when I change and save prefences file, that file reload previous version. I think, if you want to changes works correctly, chrome has to closed.

Comment: This Get is successful, but how to **Set**?

Answer (score 6):

On Windows 7 (and I guess Vista) with a default install it's stored in the file:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\User Data\Default\Preferences`

On Windows 2003 (and XP):

`%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`

The property name to look for is: `homepage`.

Answer (score 0):

A little part of the Preferences file you need.

```
},
      "homepage": "http://www.google.com/",
      "homepage_is_newtabpage": true,
      "pinned_tabs": [ {
```