# How to change Chrome homepage using C#?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, automation, browser-automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I programmatically access the Google Chrome Home or Start page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008194/how-can-i-programmatically-access-the-google-chrome-home-or-start-page)

I want to change chrome homepage with a basic c# program
the file which holds the home page is located in "C:\Documents and Settings\Danny\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" 
the problem is that i want to change it while chrome is open but no luck so far, do you have any tip for me?