# Get chrome downloads folder

Tags: c#, google-chrome, download, directory

The default downloads folder in Windows 7 is *c:\users\username\downloads* for Chrome. But default downloads folder can be set to another folder through settings. I need to find out which folder is the downloads folder. So if I set the downloads folder to *c:\dd*, then I need to find out the specific folder.

Is there a way of finding this out using *C#*? I mean I don't want to visit the chrome settings and fetch the folder path from there.

Comment: So your question is that how to setup download path for Chrome using C# Correct?

Comment: No I don't want to change it I only want to see what it is.

Comment: I suggest finding out where the settings are stored. If it's in registry or files (and it likely is), you just need to figure out where. Then writing a simple C# program that reads them out shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I was searching ages where it keeps the settings..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default locations for Chrome settings are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008194/how-can-i-programmatically-access-the-google-chrome-home-or-start-page). I actually found mine to be under '**C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default**' for Chrome **20.0.1132.47**.

If you open the **Preferences** file, you can parse the JSON to get the download folder:

```
"download": {
  "default_directory": "C:\\Users\\[UserName]\\Downloads",
  "directory_upgrade": true,
  "extensions_to_open": ""
}
```

If there is no `default_directory` value, then the directory **C:\Users\[UserName]\Downloads** is being used.

Comment: I found this in my Preferences file.

"download": {
      "directory_upgrade": true,
      "extensions_to_open": ""
   }

Comment: Okay, problem solved: if the downloads directory is the default one, then the "default_directory": ".." item does not exist. But if not, that item shows the folder.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're right. If the value is missing, then the default directory is used. Updated.