# Unable to modify value of "prompt_for_download" in chrome preferences file

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Gurus,
I am using uipath(A Ui Based Automation Tool) to download a file from a website using chrome browser.
I want browser to not prompt before downloading and just download the file in the downloads folder.
From various posts on this website i found that there exists a file called "preferences" which can be modified to solve this problem.

Before coding further i decided to do the changes in the "preferences" file manually on multiple machines, just to make sure that the changes i do in the preferences file reflect in the chrome browser as well .

I am manually modifying values for these 2 options in the preferences file.

1. download.default_directory
2. download.prompt_for_download

When i changed value for download.default_directory(Manually in Preferences file), it reflects the same in the chrome browser settings on every machine that i tested on.
But When i change value for download.prompt_for_download, it reflected in the chrome browser settings on some of the machines while on others i found that it does not reflect in the browser and rather the preferences file also seems to have reverted back to previous values.

The steps i followed are as below..

1. close any running instance of chrome
2. do the modifications in the preference file and save it
3. open chrome and go to settings>advance and downloads

i see [DreamCatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330411/dreamcatcher) pointing to a similiar situation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009195) post, but no answers there..

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help solve your issue or at least give you some direction :)

**Option#1: Chrome Settings**
Wouldn't the problem be solved by changing the settings for downloads in the browser before running the bot? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95759?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

**Option#2: Do it in UiPath**
And the other thing, is that when the prompt (to save the file) appears, couldn't you insert the path of the file that includes the default folder to save + name file + extension? (e.g. on the save path of the prompt, use type text "c:\myDocuments\downloads\filename.ext" ? I've done this in the past with UiPath...get the prompt window, type text and just modify the string being passed to carry the path, file name and extensio...then click "SAVE" or use hotkey "Enter"(if the file requires replacement, these are another 20cents you will have to program in UiPath, but it'd doable).

**Option#3: Script**
Another option, which I have not done, but see my friends do is creating BAT files to reset certain browser settings or the "registry"...so what they do is that they configure the BAT to do the changes to the browser and they add an activity (in UiPath) to invoke the BAT file every time the browser is opened by the robot.

Links for reference:

https://superuser.com/questions/59465/is-it-possible-to-download-using-the-windows-command-line

https://getadmx.com/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::DownloadDirectory

Comment: Adding to option#2, I found this: https://forum.uipath.com/t/ui-path-or-microsoft-made-download-file-from-url-activity/174352/8

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I was trying to build an asset which will save us a few clicks. I know we can navigate through the save as window but if modifying download preferences in google chrome programmatically is possible(and reliable) then i would like to go that way.