# Open a specific page or set of pages

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to know where the homepages for chrome is stored.Like in registry or any appdata foldersin windows 10.I know how to set it.Settings->On startup->Open a specific page or set of pages->http:\cdsvsdvsd.com.I need to know where this URL (http:\cdsvsdvsd.com)is stored and how it is loaded on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Programmatically access the Google Chrome Home or Start page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008194/programmatically-access-the-google-chrome-home-or-start-page)

However (I am not sure if this is a Chrome update), I found it slightly different on my machine (Windows 10). It is in the same location: my Users folder, then

> \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\

but in a file called "Secure Preferences" under

```
"session":{-, "startup_urls":["urls1","url2", etc]}
```

Comment: will i able to modify this URL?this ressts the chrome when i am trying to do so.